# Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: $(...).ready(...).then is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<script>
    function solution() {
        let pro = new Promise((res, rej) => {
            let arr = [];
            $(document).ready(function () {
                arr.push(1);
                res(arr);
            }).then((response) => {
                console.log(response);
            });
        });
    }
    solution();
</script>
```

Why is wrapping $(document).ready() in promise would generate Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: $(...).ready(...).then is not a function error? I am sure $(document).ready() works fine independently.

Comment: `}).then(...) });` must be `}); }).then(...);`

Comment: Why exactly are you putting a document ready in a promise?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ready/ It already has a promise-based signature. If you want to use a promise for `.ready`, you should use `$.ready`, not `$(document).ready()`

Answer (score 0):

See, `$(document).ready(...)`, as well as any other *event handler attachment function* in jQuery, [returns a jQuery object](https://api.jquery.com/ready/) - which is not a Promise (and doesn't have `then` method assigned). What you actually need is to shift the parens:

```js
function solution() {
  let pro = new Promise((res, rej) => {
    let arr = [];
    $(document).ready(function() {
      arr.push(1);
      res(arr);
    });
  }).then(response => console.log(response));
}
solution();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

... so that `.then()` is called on your fresh Promise (resolved after DOM is considered `ready` by jQuery code).

It's not clear, however, why do you need to use `then` directly within the same function that attaches the handler. It might be a better idea to make this function do just *one* thing - return a Promise resolved whenever document is ready. In this case you'll be able to attach more than one handler to it:

```
function whenDomIsReady() {
  const someInitialData = ['Spanish Inquisition']; // nobody expects!
  return new Promise(res => {
    $(document).ready(function() {
      res(someInitialData);
    });
  });
}
```

... then use it to attach several handlers:

```
whenDomIsReady().then(console.log);
```

Actually (kudos to @KevinB for mentioning it), this problem is already solved - in jQuery itself, with [$.ready](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ready/), available since 1.8:

```
$.when( $.ready ).then(function() {
  // Document is ready.
});
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
<script>
    function solution() {
        let pro = new Promise((res, rej) => {
            let arr = [];
            $(document).ready(function () {
                arr.push(1);
                res(arr);
            })
        })
        .then((response) => console.log(response));
    }
    solution();
</script>
```

Your then is in the wrong place. It's being called within the promise. It should follow right after.